# Autograd function in Pytorch documentation

Tags: pytorch, gradient, autograd

[image]

In the Pytorch documentation https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-autograd-tutorial-py
In the image, I am unable to understand what y.backward(v) means and why do we need to define another tensor v to do the backward operation and also how we got the results of x.grad
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`y.backward()` computes dy/dz where `z` are all the leaf nodes in the computation graph. And it stores `dy/dz` in `z.grad`.

For example: In the above case, leaf nodes are x.

`y.backward()` works when `y` is a scalar which is the case for most of the deep-learning. When `y` is a vector you have to pass another vector (`v` in the above case). You can see this as computing `d(v^Ty)/dx`.

---

To answer how we got `x.grad` note that you raise `x` by the power of 2 unless norm exceeds `1000`, so `x.grad` will be `v*k*x**(k-1)` where `k` is `2**i` and `i` is the number of times the loop was executed.

To have a less complicated example, consider this:

```
x = torch.randn(3,requires_grad=True)                                         
print(x)                                                                            
Out: tensor([-0.0952, -0.4544, -0.7430], requires_grad=True)

y = x**2   
v = torch.tensor([1.0,0.1,0.01])                                                                   
y.backward(v) 

print(x.grad)                                                                        
Out[15]: tensor([-0.1903, -0.0909, -0.0149])

print(2*v*x)                                              
Out: tensor([-0.1903, -0.0909, -0.0149], grad_fn=<MulBackward0>)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help...